# How to recreate the any? method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, enumerable, any

I am trying to recreate the enumerable module in Ruby.  I am up to the any? method and having difficulty returning true or false.  Instead each array item is returned 1 by 1.. Here is my code:

```
def my_any?
  return self.to enum unless block_given?
  self.each do |i|
    return true if i == yield(i)
  end
end

nums = [3,5,7,3,6,10,20,16]

puts nums.my_any?{|x|x==6}
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. You're missing a `return false` if the loop fails to find a match. Currently when it fails to match, it'll give the return value from `each`, which is what you're seeing.
2. It's currently always failing, because while your `return true if cond` construct is right, `any?`'s conditional is not `i == yield(i)`: you've got too many comparisons. You need just `yield(i)`.

(The `to enum` bit sounds off too, but that's unrelated to your question.)

Slotting those changes into your code:

```
def my_any?
  # FIXME: return self.to enum unless block_given?
  self.each do |i|
    return true if yield i
  end
  false
end
```

Comment: There's no need for `self`

Comment: @Stefan there is always a need in `self` in our humble lives :)

Answer (score 3):

You have three issues with your code: you should return an enumerator for this method when called without block, you should check just what `yield` returns, and you should explicitly return `false` on fail:

```
def my_any?
  return to_enum(:my_any?) unless block_given?
  each { |i| return true if yield(i) }
  false
end

nums = [3,5,7,3,6,10,20,16]

puts nums.my_any? { |x| x == 6 }
#⇒ true
lazy = nums.my_any?
lazy.each { |x| x == 6 }
#⇒ true
```

---

Or, I would better use `break`:

```
def my_any?
  return to_enum(:my_any?) unless block_given?

  each { |i| break true if yield(i) } == true
end
```

Comment: I cannot count the times when an asker wanted to recreate an `Enumerable` method and answers neglected to deal with the case where the method has no block and an enumerator is returned. Good to see you dealt with that very important aspect of the question.

Comment: Whoops! [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) only returns `true` or `false`, never an enumerator. Strange. I'd think one may wish to write, for example, `nums.any?.with_index { |x,i| x <= 6 && i >2 }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `Enumerable#any?` is relatively young, nowadays people any not that picky :)